# IllegalLocationConstraintException on CloudFront (with S3)

Tags: cdn, amazon-aws, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have created an S3 and I uploaded files on the bucket successfully. Now, I am trying to make it work with CloudFront however it is giving me

> IllegalLocationConstraintException
>
> *The ap-east-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.*

My S3 url is: http://my-bucket-name.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/local/css/app.css (this returns me the file)

CloudFront is linked to the S3, and the url: https://id.cloudfront.net/assets/local/css/app.css (this returns me the IllegalLocationConstraintException)

---

In S3 bucket > Permissions >

"Block Public Access" is Off

"Bucket Policy" is auto-generated:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "######"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hey senty got any solution for this?

Comment: @Er.Khatri Even when you auto-select the S3 in CloudFront as related bucket, you still need to put your location manually for making it work.

Comment: can you add that how we can add that? or even better if you can post that as an answer here itself so that I can upvote that also

Comment: @Er.Khatri there you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue was because my CloudFront origin was not in us-east, and when you auto-select your bucket's origin in CloudFront, it doesn't add the location prefix to the url. So make sure you add your s3 location like so:

`bucketname.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: i am still getting the error, but this time the error is different. It says no access key associated with this account when i try to access the image from s3 using alternate domain of cloudfront

Comment: actuall error i got "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

Comment: Sounds like it’s a process, right? I’d be happy to know your solution too

Comment: i needed to change delete the bucket amd re-created it in another region

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. FYI. As I am typing this message, this issue is very common in aws.

Comment: @dryleaf thanks for the heads up. I have marked it as accepted answer :)